# Save value Permently by Appliaction State using DropdownList in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have  string value which change by `dropdown_SelectedIndex` Change Event 
I dont wanna save it to database not in xml file.

I cant save it in `webconfig` because its read only.
I want to save this string value Permently untill the value would not be changed by selectedindex change event of a `downdownlist`

aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewsRows" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub ddlNewsRows_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlNewsRows.SelectedIndexChanged
        'here i wana implement Appliaction State logic'
    End Sub
```

Comment: save it in hidden field

Comment: well when i save in hidden feild then next time on page load the value would be 0 which i dont want

Comment: then store it session..!!

Comment: You want to save it permanently, but you don't want to write to a DB or to a static file.  You need to put it somewhere that will survive the application recycling...

Comment: @Sajad Lfc cant be in session hope you know why! 
@Paddy that`s actuly i want that where should i save this value

Comment: keep in cookie or cache it on server.. or else you have to put in mind :)

Comment: @Terror.Blade Session and cache will be removed automatically in server i think that`s good idea i should keep save this value in mind :P

Comment: cache can be stored till iss restart. it has noabsoluteexpiration . but after restart it will distroy. you can store it for n number of days